# Tax Not Displayed in Opencart Checkout page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I have recently made some changes in TAX , i made -10% of tax (GST)

But now i am not getting this tax (GST) in checkout page and invoice page ( but amount is subtracting from sub total

here is some images of my tax setting 
[image: tax rate]

[image: tax class]

[image: checkout page]

is -tax amount will not appear ? any clue that where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

```
its GEO ZONE PLAY A IMPORTANT ROLE IN THIS PROBLEM
IF YOU ARE WOKING IN DELHI THEN OPENCART AUTOMETIC CHECK YOU GEO LOCATION AT TIME OF CHECKOUT SO FOLLOW THIS STEP
1. SYSTEM -> LOCALISATION ->GEO ZONE.
2. ADD NEW ZONE WHERE YOU ARE WORKING (IN MY CASE DELHI)
3. THEN GO TAX RATES -> AND SELECT YOU GEO ZONE YOU CREATED.
THAT ITS




If this is helpful for you give a like.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the tax to your product then it will show in the checkout page go to Admin->Product->edit under data tab find the Tax Class . use that tax class so it will appear in the checkout

Answer (score 0):

You should have to select tax class in your product. Without selecting tax class in your product it will not display in the cart as well as checkout page.

Please follow the following step to select tax class in product

> Admin → Catalog → Product → Edit/Add Product → Goto Data Tab → Select Tax Class drop-down on it.